# Bootstrap: Striped div table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap css lib.
I know how to make striped table with this lib but how to make striped div's?

For ex, in tables you would do this:

```
<table id="newtable" class="table table-bordered table-striped fixedtable">
    <thead>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Info</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">                
                <div>text 1</div> 
                <div>text 2</div>  
                <div>text 3</div>  
                <div>text 4</div>                                
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>    
</table>
```

And I need to repeat that "styling" with divs like this:

```
<div class="row"><div class="col">Text 1 White BG</div></div>
<div class="row"><div class="col">Text 2 Grey BG</div></div>
<div class="row"><div class="col">Text 3 White BG</div></div>
<div class="row"><div class="col">Text 4 Grey BG</div></div>
```

Question is: How to make: `<div>text 1</div>, <div>text 2</div>, <div>text 3</div>, <div>text 4</div>` striped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter Bootstrap's striping only works for table rows. So in order to stripe your divs you need to add each of them into a new row. For instance:

```
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>text 1</div> 
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>text 2</div>  
        </td>
    </tr>
    ...
```

Also I'm not sure what you trying to achieve with `colspan="3"`. If you want to create a proper table you need to create new `td` for each column. For instance:

```
    <tr>
        <td>2013-07-22</td>
        <td>Text for info field 1</td>
        <td>9.99</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: the problem that is in this cell I have scrollable list which I'm getting from the server.

Comment: How is that a problem? It doesn't matter where you get the data as long as you end up with correct HTML.

Comment: somehow with existing layout it works better when I'm using div's. But if it's impossible to do it with striped-div I'm will change it for striped-table.... thnx

Comment: Another thing to note is that it's perfectly valid HTML to nest a table within a `<td>`

Answer (score 10):

Add class legend to your container and then for every other row actually in the divs within that row you can apply a format

```
CSS

.legend .row:nth-of-type(odd) div {
background-color:antiquewhite;
}
.legend .row:nth-of-type(even) div {
background: #FFFFFF;
}

<div class="container legend">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-2">text</div>
     <div class="col-sm-2">more Text</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-2">text</div>
     <div class="col-sm-2">more Text</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Solved to me!

Comment: This is simple and efficient. Thank you

Answer (score 8):

use `td div:nth-of-type(odd|even)`

The following CSS3 example works in modern browsers

```
<style>
td div:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background: #e0e0e0;
}
td div:nth-of-type(even) {
    background: #FFFFFF;
}
</style>
<table id="newtable" class="table table-bordered table-striped fixedtable">
    <thead>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Info</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">                
                <div>text 1</div> 
                <div>text 2</div>  
                <div>text 3</div>  
                <div>text 4</div>                                
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>    
</table>
```